# exclude dislay iPod when submitting an app to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, submit, itunes, ipod

When I submit an app to iTunes Connect, because my app doesn't support iPod so, in device family (compatibility) I don't need display iPod. I set up magnetometer.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app requires the magnetometer then specifying that in 'Required Capabilities' is sufficient.

You cannot (and should not) exclude specific devices. You should work out what device capabilities your app needs and specify those as described in [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html). Then the Store will use that to determine what devices to list. In this way you do not unnecessarily restrict the market for your app and it remains compatible with future variants of Apple products.

iPod appears in the device families because the family is called 'iPhone / iPod Touch'. But that is OK as iTunes will not allow an installation on a device that does not include the other required capabilities.